# objective-c should I remove observing NSWindowWillCloseNotification?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am watching my mac app's preferences window status with the following code in `- (void)awakeFromNib`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowWillClose:)
                                             name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                           object:self.prefsWindow];
```

And the method `windowWillClose:` is the following

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Received Notification!");
    [[self.customOptField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
}
```

I'd like to continue to watch preferences window status while my app is working.  i.e.  Every time preferences window would be closed, I'd like to call `windowWillClose:` method.

Currently my code seems to work fine.  But I wonder that should I remove observe `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`?  If should be removed, when should I?

Any advice would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVERY notification you register, should be removed in the opposite call.

for `awakeFromNib` which is only called once after init, the opposite is `dealloc`. So remove it there!

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(windowWillClose:)
                                                 name: NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                               object: self.prefsWindow];
}

...

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                                  object: self.prefsWindow ];
}
```

Comment: I firstly heard `dealloc`.  Thank you.  You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the observer before you relinquish your last strong reference to the specific window that you're observing, if you ever do, and before the observer object itself is deallocated.

In the code you showed, the observer is `self` and the window you're observing is `self.prefsWindow`. Assuming that `prefsWindow` is a strong property, do you ever clear it to `nil` or assign a new window to it? If so, you need to remove the observer before doing so. And you would presumably want to start observing the new window, too.

And, of course, you have to remove the observer in `self`'s `-dealloc` method (as Daij-Djan says), for two reasons: 1) that object is the observer, and 2) the object will be releasing its last strong reference to the observed window.

Comment: Your explanation might be should be understand, but since I'm a beginner,  your explanation is hard to read and understand.